# print(self.request.user.id) returns None

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a Django REST App where I want to do the log in. I need the id of the currend logged in user and when I print it, it returns None. This is my code:
serializer.py

```
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):


    username = serializers.CharField(
        label="Username",
        write_only=True
    )
    password = serializers.CharField(
        label="Password",
        # This will be used when the DRF browsable API is enabled
        style={'input_type': 'password'},
        trim_whitespace=False,
        write_only=True
    )
```

view.py

```
class LoginAPI(APIView):

def post(self, request):
    username = request.data['username']
    password = request.data['password']

    user = User.objects.filter(username=username).first()

    if user is None:
        raise AuthenticationFailed('User not found!')

    if not user.check_password(password):
        raise AuthenticationFailed('Incorrect password!')

    payload = {
        'id': user.id,

    }

    token = jwt.encode(payload, 'secret', algorithm='HS256').decode('utf-8')

    response = Response()

    response.set_cookie(key='token', value=token, httponly=True)
    response.data = {
        'token': token
    }
    print(self.request.user.id)
    return response
```

I don't know what I have to change in my log in view in order to print the id, not None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't login yet in that `post` function. So `self.request.user` does not exist.

```
print(user.id)
```

Comment: True, but I thought that would help me out with my problem. I want to log in as an user and then I want to see only my active tasks. In my app I have more users and I want to log in from my phone as one of the users and end one of my active tasks when done. 
That' s why I asked about self.request.user.id. I thought it was something wrong with my log in function.

Comment: `self.request.user` exists when it's called in the authorized API view.

Comment: Ok, I understand. When I access my active tasks from django rest I can see them, but when I access them from my flutter mobile app it returns nothing.